# Double stack of sticky piston, top wont pull?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

version 1.12

Only not extended pistons can be pulled back, that I understand. So the top one needs to retract earlier, than when the bottom retracts it will bring the top one. That works, BUT:

Even if I manage the timing so that the top piston is pulled back correctly by the bottom one, when its pulled back only the piston comes back, not the block on top of it.

I have 3 repeaters at the bottom one, so the delay is enormous..:[image]
Than when I retract:[image]
When the bottom retracts, the top one have been retracted much earlier..so I guess its impossible? Im not much experienced with minecraft.

Is that intended behavior? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Some misconceptions: 1. You CAN pull an extended piston. 2. Piston pulls the adjacent block only while retracting, not when the whole piston is being moved. So pulling an extended piston pulls only that extended piston, not whatever it was touching. The proper sequence is to first pull the block (retract middle piston), then pull the middle piston (retract bottom piston), then extend and retract middle piston to pull the block the rest of the way. Or in your case, just use sand or gravel...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your circuit can work but you are missing a last pulse to the upper piston once both pistons have retracted to retract the block.

I recreated what I saw in the images to modify your current circuit.  I reduced the delays you had and added a pulse device.

Here it is extended.  The two repeaters, redstone dust, and observer form the pulse device.
[image: Extended]

Here it is retracted.
[image: Retracted]

Here is a side view for timing of repeaters
[image: Timing]

This is a different circuit example all together.  It is the most compact, fastest circuit I could come up with if you want to start from scratch or want to build another one elsewhere.
[image: Double Extender]

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are trying to make what's called a **vertical piston double extender**! There are quite a couple of online tutorials available you could try checking out.

Anyway, this is what I can tell is happening to the pistons in the picture right now:

1. Lever turns off
2. The torches carry up the signal and the top piston retracts, pulling the wood planks down
3. After a few more seconds, the bottom piston retracts, pulling down the top piston

The problem is that after all the redstone action, *the block doesn't get pulled back down*, so you need to send a small pulse to extend then retract the top piston to pull down the block.

Here's a design that could work, using an observer block to add a pulse:

Pistons Extended
[image: Piston Extended]
Pistons Retracted
[image: Piston Retracted]

Different angle views:
[image: Angle 2]

[image: Angle 3]